# How to match a string that doesn't start with <del> but ends with ######## with regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

In each row of df['Description'], there is a user field that has 8 digit numbers that I need to grab. But I do not want to grab the ones with <del'> in front of it. The numbers that should be retrieved are 11111113 and 11111114.
 The data looks something like this (without the single quotation):

```
<del'>11111111 Random text here </del'><br>
<br'><del'>11111112 Random text here </del'></br'><br>
<p'>11111113 Random text here </p'><br>
<br'>11111114 Random text here </br'>
```

I have tried variations of this:

```
df['SN_Fixed_List']=[re.findall(r'\b(?!<del>)\s*[0-9]{8}\b',x) for x in df['Description']]
```

Comment: Something like `df['SN_Fixed_List'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'^(?!<del).*\b(\d{8})\b', expand=False)`? See https://regex101.com/r/ieAvvB/1. Even try `.str.extract(r'\b(\d{8})\b')`

Comment: Please check the data sample, I edited it but I am not sure your real data looks exactly like that.

Comment: I made a clarification in my question. Those seem get all options but I only want the last two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['SN_Fixed_List'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'^(?!.*<del'>).*\b(\d{8})\b', expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ieAvvB/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*<del'>)` - no `<del'>` allowed in the string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\b(\d{8})\b` - eight digits as whole word (captured into Group 1 the value of which is output with `Series.str.extract`).